# Why does DateTime.parse not recognize this invalid input as an invalid date?

Tags: ruby, datetime

Can anyone explain me why `DateTime.parse` returns this, instead of failing, which is the behaviour I'd expect when passing it an invalid date?

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse "X5pxmDwewKlIgJ_G0HX6TI2sMoY1XOgOcz09oQ4RO9U"
=> #<DateTime: 2017-01-09T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457763j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

I tried to leave only numbers, but then it gives `ArgumentError: invalid date`, also I tried to modify a little that string, but again, it fails:

```
DateTime.parse "X5px4fGHewKlIgJ_G0635I2sMoY1XOgOcz09oQ4ROA1"
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)?

Comment: Seriously though, what do you expect `DateTime.parse` to return?

Comment: I expect it to fail as with any other invalid string

Comment: The thing is, `parse` needs to understand so many distinct, sometimes contradictory formats that it simply cannot be correct 100% of the time. It is fuzzy by nature. Some correct strings won't get parsed correctly while some incorrect strings will get parsed.

Comment: I edited the title & body to make clearer what you are asking about

Comment: If you want to use it for validation, you can check out `#strptime` instead. It requires a specific pattern.

Comment: @EricDuminil yes, I know, I'm just intrigued

Comment: @ndn I'm aware of `#strptime` but I don't have a fixed format input, I got dates from many sources and `#parse` really helps with that. Of course, this one is not a date but I got surprised when it didn't failed to parse it.

Comment: @Redithion, agreed it's surprising. The only way to understand what happened is to check the parser code. Even then, this would just satisfy your curiosity. The practical answer should be that there is no guarantee that `#parse` will raise an error if invalid looking dates are given.

Comment: Why people downvoted the question? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Redithion, I upvoted it, it's interested indeed. It's a trend I've found on SO - questions that ask *"what is happening here internally"* as opposed to *"how to solve this problem"* tend to get downvoted. :/

Comment: @ndn well thanks, and thanks for the explanation. It's a pitty though, I mean, the answer from Stefan is amazingly helpful. He even got a few upvotes so the answer is good but not the question? odd

Comment: @Redithion, to be fair, the existence of a good answer does not necessarily mean the question wasn't of poor quality. Or that a poor quality question wasn't worth asking. There is a reason we have the [Reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge.

Comment: @ndn quite interesting! I wasn't aware of that badge, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parse` tries hard to extract a date. You can use [`Date#_parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_parse) to see what it finds:

```
require 'date'
Date._parse 'X5pxmDwewKlIgJ_G0HX6TI2sMoY1XOgOcz09oQ4RO9U'
#=> {:hour=>0, :mday=>9}
```

`:hour=>0` is due to `0H` (H=hour)

```
Date._parse '0H'
#=> {:hour=>0}
```

And `:mday=>9` is because of `09`:

```
Date._parse '09'
#=> {:mday=>9}
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what I was looking for. Also thanks for `#_parse`, I think it will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem. It's got a wide range of patterns it can parse. While there are sure to be holes in it too it returns a sane response to your string:

```
[4] (pry) main: 0> Chronic.parse('X5pxmDwewKlIgJ_G0HX6TI2sMoY1XOgOcz09oQ4RO9U')
nil
```

Take a look at the "Usage" and "Examples" sections in the documentation to get an idea what it can do. It's impressive.